# show tooltip when function is called in d3 js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip

I try to show the previously generated tooltip when the element is selected in a dropdown list. I am using d3 js version 3 and d3-tip.

```
    function initialize_map(id){
      // select map
      var svg = d3.select(id).append("svg")
        .attr("width", map_width)
        .attr("height", map_height)
    
      // add tooltip
      var tooltip = d3.tip()
                  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
                  .attr("id", "tool-" + id)
                  .offset([-5, 0])
                  .html(d => get_location_info(d, "tool-" + id))
    
      // display the municipalities
      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "municipalities")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(municipalities)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("id", function(d){ return d.GEO_ID })
        .attr("d", path)
        .on('mouseover', tooltip.show)
        .on('mouseout', tooltip.hide)

svg.call(tooltip)

}

function showSelectedMunic(munic_info_id){
var tooltip = d3.select('#tool-map1')



  svg = d3.select("#map1")
  svg.selectAll(".municipalities")
  .selectAll("path")
  .filter(function(d) { return d.id == munic_info_id  })
  .call(tooltip.show)
  

}
```

I can select the correct element when the function `showSelectedMunic`is called but somehow `.call(tooltip.show)` does give me the error `Uncaught TypeError: callback is undefined`. When I would change this code to `.on('mouseout', tooltip.show)`it would work. How do I have to modify it in order to show the tooltip?

Comment: Use `mouseenter` event to trigger tooltip visibility

Comment: I tried it but it did not work

Comment: I also tried to select the whole svg when event mouseover is triggered...did not work as well

Comment: I hope this can help: https://jsfiddle.net/mrovinsky/qky8z5m4/

Comment: I have thought about creating an own tooltip as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting, I have a workaround. I just manually trigger the event `mouseover`:

```
function changeSelectedMunic(munic_info_id){

var evt = new MouseEvent("mouseover");

svg = d3.select("#map1")

svg.selectAll(".municipalities")
  .selectAll("path")
  .filter(function(d) { return d.id == munic_info_id  })
  .node().dispatchEvent(evt);

}
```